# Google Spreadsheet array formula to compare plus title and blanks

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to compare 2 columns (A and B). If they match, the array formula should print "Match" in column C, if not, it should print "No Match".

I've been able to succesfully achieve the above with:

```
={"Column Title Goes Here";arrayformula(IF(A2:A=B2:B,"Match","No match"))}
```

However, any blank cells in columns A and B still print "Match" in corresponding cells in column C.

Is there a way to not print anything in column C if there's nothing in A and B? See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
={"Column Title Goes Here"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A="")+(B2:B=""),,
 IF(A2:A=B2:B, "Match", "No match")))}
```

[image: 0]

---

if you want it less strict change `+` sign to `*`

Comment: Thank you for the formula. It does exactly what I needed.

However, I was surprised to see if, for example, I have a value in A4 and nothing in B4 -- the formula doesn't seem to do anything. It seems like it only works when the two cells have values. Shouldn't it trigger a "No Match" in this case since technically they are both different?

Is there a way to make it also work when only one of the cells has a value?

Comment: try: `={"Column Title Goes Here"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(A2:A=B2:B, "Match", "No match"))}`